# Java interfaces reduction in visibility, only NOT

Tags: java, interface, class-visibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reduce visibility when implementing interface in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588015/reduce-visibility-when-implementing-interface-in-java)

I must be missing something obvious, but i am getting:

> Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method

And I don't see how.  This is my interface:

```
interface QueryBuilderPart {
    StringBuilder toStringBuilder();
}
```

And this is my implementation:

```
public class Stupid implements QueryBuilderPart {
    @Override
    StringBuilder toStringBuilder() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Both the class and the implementation are in the same package.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default interface's method is `public`, but you reduce it to default visibility, which is package level visibility.

So the following two block of code are the same:

```
interface QueryBuilderPart {
    StringBuilder toStringBuilder();
}

interface QueryBuilderPart {
    public abstract StringBuilder toStringBuilder();
}
```

Note that interface's method is `abstract` as well

So you should do as following:

```
public class Stupid implements QueryBuilderPart {
    @Override
    public StringBuilder toStringBuilder() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not just by default - every method declared by an interface is implicitly public, even if it's not explicitly declared as such. To get a package-level abstract method, you'll have to use an abstract class, not an interface.